# Get input element from innerHTML string

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the input field from the innerHTML which is a string? getElementById does not work obviously.

```
div.innerHTML = "<input id=\"ValueField\" name=\"test1\" value=\"1\" type=\"hidden\">"
```

Comment: could you be more precise please? a jsFiddle would be useful

Comment: Clear your question. What you want ? input field or value ?

Comment: well your js above is invalid for a start. you have un-delimited "'s

Comment: @Liam the code is copied from the visual studio debugger... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
div.innerHTML = '<input id="ValueField" name="test1" value="1" type="hidden" />';
var input = document.getElementById('ValueField');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get it as a string this is the solution

```
div.innerHTML = '<input id="ValueField" name="test1" value="1" type="hidden">'
```